# Implementing Magento security patch

Tags: security, magento, magento-1.7, patch

I am running `Magento CE 1.7.0.2` and I want to apply below two patches.

```
PATCH_SUPEE-5345_CE_1.7.0.2_v1-2015-02-10-08-11-22.sh
PATCH_SUPEE-1533_EE_1.12.x_v1-2015-02-10-08-19-16.sh
```

I am running below command to apply first patch.

```
sh PATCH_SUPEE-5345_CE_1.7.0.2_v1-2015-02-10-08-11-22.sh
```

But it shows me with some errors shown in below screen.

[image: Implementing Magento security patch]

Can you please tell me what is the issue and how to resolve it?

Comment: Is /var/www/dev the root directory of your magento installation?

Comment: @hellcode yes its root directory of dev instance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hunk #1 FAILED at 1. What's that mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14282617/hunk-1-failed-at-1-whats-that-mean)

Comment: @b.enoit.be this question is not duplicate of shared link because this one is only related to Magento

Comment: @TahirYasin it is because that have nothing to do with Magento, but with the patch command. Read the explanation on the link, please. And for TLDR : that means you do have a file which cannot be patched because it has diverged from his version on the stock 1.7.0.2, and this file is lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php as the command line is saying it to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error mean what your file have some modifications.This is last file which should be changed by patch so you can patch it manually:

1. Open lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php in some editor and go to the line 2672. Near this line you find next code block:

   ```
   $query = '';
   if (is_array($condition)) {
       if (isset($condition['field_expr'])) {
           $fieldName = str_replace('#?', $this->quoteIdentifier($fieldName), $condition['field_expr']);
           unset($condition['field_expr']);
       }
   $key = key(array_intersect_key($condition, $conditionKeyMap));
   ```
2. Remove this part:

   ```
   if (isset($condition['field_expr'])) {
       $fieldName = str_replace('#?', $this->quoteIdentifier($fieldName), $condition['field_expr']);
       unset($condition['field_expr']);
   }
   ```
3. Save the file. Patching done.

Comment: Mysql.php was already updated, reverted it to original version then applied patch, it worked !