# How to resolve error " Hunk #2 FAILED at 456. 1 out of 2 hunks FAILED"

Tags: patch

I am trying to run the following command in ubuntu terminal

```
patch -p0 -i adjustmentFile.patch
```

That is giving the following error

```
patching file ./src/helpStructures/CastaliaModule.cc
patching file ./src/node/communication/mac/tunableMac/TunableMAC.cc
Hunk #2 FAILED at 456.
1 out of 2 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file ./src/node/communication/mac/tunableMac/TunableMAC.cc.rej
```

I tried almost all the ways suggested in the link [Hunk #1 FAILED at 1. What's that mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14282617/hunk-1-failed-at-1-whats-that-mean?answertab=active#tab-top). However, nothing worked.

Here is my version detail

> VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Jun 06 2019 17:31:41)
>   Included patches: 1-1453

The patch file:

```
diff -r -u ./src/helpStructures/CastaliaModule.cc ./src/helpStructures/CastaliaModule.cc
--- ./src/helpStructures/CastaliaModule.cc  2010-12-09 09:56:47.000000000 -0300
+++ ./src/helpStructures/CastaliaModule.cc  2011-12-20 00:16:39.944320051 -0300
@@ -180,6 +180,8 @@
            classPointers.resourceManager = getParentModule()->getParentModule()->getSubmodule("ResourceManager");
        else if (name.compare("SensorManager") == 0)
            classPointers.resourceManager = getParentModule()->getSubmodule("ResourceManager");
+       else if (name.compare("Routing") == 0)
+                   classPointers.resourceManager = getParentModule()->getParentModule()->getSubmodule("ResourceManager");
        else
            opp_error("%s module has no rights to call drawPower() function", getFullPath().c_str());
         if (!classPointers.resourceManager) 
Only in ./src/helpStructures: CastaliaModule.cc~
diff -r -u ./src/node/communication/mac/tunableMac/TunableMAC.cc ./src/node/communication/mac/tunableMac/TunableMAC.cc
--- ./src/node/communication/mac/tunableMac/TunableMAC.cc   2011-03-30 02:14:34.000000000 -0300
+++ ./src/node/communication/mac/tunableMac/TunableMAC.cc   2011-12-19 23:57:43.894686687 -0300
@@ -405,6 +405,8 @@
 void TunableMAC::fromRadioLayer(cPacket * pkt, double rssi, double lqi)
 {
    TunableMacPacket *macFrame = dynamic_cast <TunableMacPacket*>(pkt);
+   macFrame->getMacRadioInfoExchange().RSSI = rssi;
+   macFrame->getMacRadioInfoExchange().LQI = lqi;
    if (macFrame == NULL){
        collectOutput("TunableMAC packet breakdown", "filtered, other MAC");
        return;
@@ -454,7 +456,8 @@
        }

        case DATA_FRAME:{
-           toNetworkLayer(macFrame->decapsulate());
+           cPacket *netPkt = decapsulatePacket(macFrame);
+           toNetworkLayer(netPkt);
            collectOutput("TunableMAC packet breakdown", "received data pkts");
            if (macState == MAC_STATE_RX) {
                cancelTimer(ATTEMPT_TX);
Only in ./src/node/communication/mac/tunableMac: TunableMAC.cc~
```

Comment: Why not just edit the file by hand?  It looks like only a couple lines have changed.

Answer (score 2):

Patching takes some changes made to a file X, and applies them to a different instance of file X.  That is, suppose you start with generation 1 of file X; you make changes to get generation 2-a, and someone else starts with generation 1 to make generation 2-b.  Now you want to take his edits that created his generation 2-b, and apply them to your generation 2-a.

If 'his' changes clash with 'your' changes, they cannot be automatically patched.

You'll need to look at the changes being made in hunk 2.

```
-           toNetworkLayer(macFrame->decapsulate());
+           cPacket *netPkt = decapsulatePacket(macFrame);
+           toNetworkLayer(netPkt);
```

and figure out what you want the result to look like. Someone needs to know what the result is supposed to be.  You can't resolve conflicts without knowledge of intent.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. I will look into this.