# BLCR installation giving "code model kernel does not support PIC mode" error

Tags: linux, kernel, blcr

I'm trying to install BLCR (v0.8.5) on a Ubuntu Server 22.04 VM.
Since it supports only kernels up to the 3.7.1 version, I chose to build that kernel version so that I can build BLCR without having to change to an older Ubuntu version.
However, when I run the "make" command, after following the steps defined at [2.1 Configuring BLCR](https://gasnet-bugs.lbl.gov/blcr/doc/html/BLCR_Admin_Guide.html), it gives me the "code model kernel does not support PIC mode" error.

I already tried [Kernel doesn't support PIC mode for compiling?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/851433/kernel-doesnt-support-pic-mode-for-compiling) solution. Using this solution gave me a hunk error when applying the mkfile.patch fix, but I managed to solve that by [Hunk #1 FAILED at 1. What's that mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14282617/hunk-1-failed-at-1-whats-that-mean). Still, even though it seems to work for some, I still get the same PIC error when building the linux kernel.